# Error con el intent en java

Tags: java, android

Tengo un recycleview con un botón que al presionarlo me lleve a una activity pero al poner mi intent me marca un error con starActivity, me dice que tengo que agregar el método startActivity creo que el error seria con mi context pero no estoy seguro.
Estere seria mi adapter.

```
private final Context context;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderDireccionesGuardadas viewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

    viewHolder.textViewDireccion.setText(listDirecciones.get(position).getDireccion());

    viewHolder.btnEditarDireccion.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        openActivity();
    });
}
public void openActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditarDireccionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: En tu constructor inicializas `context`? Por que si no, puede usar la variable view `v`. `v.getContext().startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero modifica tu función que realiza el intent para que esta reciba el contexto y lo use para generar el intent:

```
public void openActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditarDireccionActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Ahora obten el contexto desde `onBindViewHolder()`, puedes usar:

```
Context context = viewHolder.btnEditarDireccion.getContext();
```

ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderDireccionesGuardadas viewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {

    viewHolder.textViewDireccion.setText(listDirecciones.get(position).getDireccion());

    viewHolder.btnEditarDireccion.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        openActivity(viewHolder.btnEditarDireccion.getContext());
    });
}
```